# "the user cancelled authentication" when using authWithOAuthPopup from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I am trying to implement a Firebase login (via Facebook) in a Chrome extension.

I use the following code within the background.js script

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://DB.firebaseio.com");    
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {  
    alert(error);
});
```

authData is null and the error presented is "Firebase:the user cancelled authentication".

Logging in with email/password seems to work without a problem.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that the Chrome browser is not allowing you to launch pop-ups from the Chrome extension, which is expected. The error you're seeing is due to a premature close of the popup - in this case browser enforced but otherwise indistinguishable from a user-prevented popup.

Because browser extensions do not have any notion of an "origin", i.e. their content is not server from an external domain, they are unsuitable for the OAuth popup and redirect flows because the authenticating app cannot verify access domain.

I would recommend creating a web page on a real, hosted domain to go along with your extension, and communicate back to the extension once authentication is complete.